# pasting input to command line with multiple carriage returns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to ruby and have written a program that takes several lines of data (actually a JSON) and converts it into a table in the command line.  Everything works fine with the JSON data embedded in the program but I would like to have it prompt the user to paste the data into the command line.  I know about `gets` and `chomp`, but since a JSON is formatted with multiple lines/carriage returns, when I paste in the command line it takes each line as a separate entry.  I feel like the answer is simple but I'm having a hard time finding info online. I just want it to take everything I paste all at once and ignore all carriage returns.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a similiar question, with a not so pretty answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839940/ruby-gets-that-works-over-multiple-lines - Otherwise: Would it be an option to prompt the user for a file name / path, and then read the json from the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're taking input via the console, `$stdin` in technical parlance, and you want to receive multiple, independent multi-line objects you'll need to have some kind of delimiter.

This could be as simple as one or more blank lines between each JSON object, or it could be a marker like `END` or `--`.

It depends on how your JSON data is formatted, as blank lines within a JSON object are valid, yet are not normally emitted by most JSON generators.

Don't forget that the UNIX model strongly encourages you to be able to do things like this:

```
processor < input.json
```

Or things like this:

```
processor *.json
```

Where you can receive multiple files via `ARGV` and process those sequentially. That avoids a lot of this mess.