# 'gets' doesn't wait for user input

Tags: ruby, input

I'm attempting to develop a program on repl.it using its Ruby platform. Here's what I've got:

```
puts "Copy the entire request page and paste it into this console, then 
hit ENTER."
request_info = gets("Edit Confirmation").chomp.gsub!(/\s+/m, ' 
').strip.split(" ")

puts "What is your name?"
your_name = gets.chomp
puts "Thanks, #{your_name}!"
```

The way I've got it, the user pastes a multi-line request, which ends with `"Edit Confirmation"`, and then it splits the request, word-by-word, into its own array for me to parse and pull the relevant data.

But I can't seem to use the `gets` command a second time after initially inquiring the user for a multi-line input at the start. Any other `gets` command I attempt to use after that is skipped, and the program ends.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is doing something quite unusual: By passing a string to the `gets` method, you are actually [changing the input separator](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-gets):

```
gets(sep, limit [, getline_args]) → string or nil
```

> Reads the next “line'' from the I/O stream; lines are separated by sep.

The reason why your code is not working as you expect is because a trailing `"\n"` character is left in the input buffer - so calling `gets` a second time instantly returns this string.

Perhaps the easiest way to resolve this would just be to absorb this character in the first `gets` call:

```
request_info = gets("Edit Confirmation\n").chomp.gsub!(/\s+/m, ' ').strip.split(" ")
```

For a "complex" multi-line input like this, it would be more common to pass a file name parameter to the ruby script, and read this file rather than pasting it into the terminal.

Or, you could use `gets(nil)` to read until an `EOF` character and ask the user to press `CTRL+D` to signify the end of the multi-line input.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Unfortunately, it's important that users be able to paste in the entire document. I tried adding the new line to the initial 'gets', but now the gets doesn't end. As for CTRL + D, the repl.it website doesn't allow for that, as it's in a browser.

Comment: @SirPuffingtons With your original implementation, what happens if you call `request_info = gets("Edit Confirmation"); leftover = gets; p leftover`? What value is left behind? Perhaps, for example, you're on a Windows machine and actually entering `\r\n` as the remainder? - Try absorbing that in the original `gets` call.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could write simple loop around a standard `gets` command and read one line at a time, until the line matches your "end of file" special string. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841043/1954610), but checking `while (text = gets.chomp) != "Edit Confirmation"`. I would probably prefer this solution, as it's clearer what your code is supposed to do.